# Why is my compiler creating duplicate assembly functions

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-optimization, icc

I was taking a look at a cod file that the compiler produced for a C file and noticed that the same function is defined twice except one of them has `..0` append to the mangled name and has `.globl` and `.protected` as well. The function is only defined once in the C file. I assume this is so that 1 of them is visible outside of the file? Why would the compiler do this?

For example:

```
# -- Begin  _ZN9wikipedia7article6formatE
    .text
# mark_begin;
       .align    16,0x90
    .protected _ZN9wikipedia7article6formatE
    .globl _ZN9wikipedia7article6formatE
_ZN9wikipedia7article6formatE:
```

vs

```
# -- Begin  _ZN9wikipedia7article6formatE..0
    .text
# mark_begin;
       .align    16,0x90

_ZN9wikipedia7article6formatE..0:
```

Comment: What compiler is it, and with what options?  It might be an example of [function cloning](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2009-10/msg00279.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icc compiler is famous for compiling the same function multiple times for different processors and putting startup code in for which one to use at runtime. I suspect that's what's happening here.

Comment: Ok that explains it. Thanks!